# Is it safe to pass NULL to modf(), modff(), or modfl()?

Tags: c, math, null, floating-point, undefined-behavior

These functions are to split a floating point number into the integer portion and the fraction portion. Is it safe to pass NULL to the second parameter if I don't want to write an integer portion?

Comment: Usually, for standard function, if not explicitly stated otherwise, passing NULL as a pointer to output  buffer is UB.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ok then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **not** safe.  The C standard mentions nothing regarding NULL being allowed for that parameter.

In fact, attempting to set the second parameter to NULL causes a segfault on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

C 2018 7.12.6.12 2 says “… They store the integral part (in floating-point format) in the object pointed to by `iptr`.” There is no exception stated for `iptr` being null, so we may conclude that `iptr` must point to an object (cannot be null).

Further, optional Annex F says “`modf` behaves as though implemented by”:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <fenv.h>
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
double modf(double value, double *iptr) {
    int save_round = fegetround();
    fesetround(FE_TOWARDZERO);
    *iptr = nearbyint(value);
    fesetround(save_round);
    return copysign(
        isinf(value) ? 0.0:
            value - (*iptr), value);
}
```

Here we see an explicit store to `*ptr` with no check for null. This is for when an implementation supports Annex F (IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic, effectively IEEE 754), but it confirms the above interpretation of 7.12.6.12 as it would be bizarre if `modf` allowed a null argument only if Annex F were not adopted.